# I have 1 list and want to use 1 list and create a new list with the data

Tags: apex, list

```
        list<Contact> listOfContact = new List<Contact>();            
        
        for (Contact conObj : listCon)
        {  
            if (String.isBlank(conObj.accountid))   
            {  
                listOfContact.add(conObj);  
            }  
        }  
        list<Contact> conlis= [Select id, firstname,lastname,MobilePhone from   listOfContact];
```

(I know its not correct please help I am learning only)

I have to create new list that has the data of listOfContact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for data from additional fields on the Contact records that are held within `listCon`, you need to requery.

```
List<Contact> listOfContact = new List<Contact>();

for (Contact conObj : listCon) {  
    if (String.isBlank(conObj.accountid)){  
        listOfContact.add(conObj);  
    }  
}

List<Contact> conlis = [Select id, firstname,lastname,MobilePhone from Contact where id in :listOfContact];
```

To make an exact copy, you can use [List.clone()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_list.htm#apex_System_List_clone).

Comment: No its not working

Comment: you have used from Contact in query which takes record from contacts only .. I want records which is in listOfContact

Comment: `where id in :listOfContact` ensures your results from the Contact table are only those that exist by `Id` in the memory `listOfContact`.

Comment: Yay It worked Now thank you for helping